# Rsync failing with "file too large"

Tags: linux, rsync, fedora

I am writing what should be a simple backup script to copy all of my media files to an external USB drive. There seems to be one file that it chokes on and I'm not sure why. Just trying to copy that one file I get:

```
[satori7@tyson Scripts]$ sudo rsync -zvr /home/Media/Movies/Truth.In.24.ESPNHD.720p.HDTV.x264.mkv  /media/video
[sudo] password for satori7: 
sending incremental file list
Truth.In.24.ESPNHD.720p.HDTV.x264.mkv
rsync: write failed on "/media/video/Truth.In.24.ESPNHD.720p.HDTV.x264.mkv": File too large (27)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(389) [receiver=3.1.0]
```

Oddly, it does copy serveral files that are around 4 GB, but this one is slightly larger at 4.4 GB. Does anyone know if rsync has some sort of limit?

This is on Fedora 20 copying to a USB drive that is mounted as vfat.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rsync isn't the limiting factor here. Your issue is likely due to the fact that [vfat doesn't support file sizes larger than 4GB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32).

In this case, do you have any other formatting options for the destination drive?

Comment: Well, if it were a snake it would've bit me. I should have caught that. Many thanks.

Comment: Update: Formatted as ext3 and was able to rsync the file with no problems. Thanks again. :)